# last year, this year, next year with php DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to create a dropbox that will display the last year, the current year and the next year using the php DateTime object.

In my current code I create three objects and have to call a method on 2 of them. This seems a bit heavy on the resources.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$last_year=new DateTime();
$last_year->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
$next_year = new DateTime();
$next_year->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
echo date_format($last_year, 'Y').' '.date_format($today, 'Y').' '.date_format($next_year, 'Y');
```

another way I found to only use 1 object is

```
$today = new DateTime();
echo date_format($today->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y')), 'Y').' '.date_format($today->add(new DateInterval('P1Y')), 'Y').' '.date_format($today->add(new DateInterval('P1Y')), 'Y');
```

but that will become very confusing.
Can someone tell me a better way to do this using `DateTime()`? As I will need something similar for months ?

Comment: `"This seems a bit heavy on the resources."` Worry about it if it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can also limit the call of `new DateInterval('P1Y')` by creating one object and using it for all three calculations?

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y');

$dateTime = new DateTime();
$lastYear = $dateTime->sub($interval)->format('Y');

$dateTime = new DateTime();
$nextYear = $dateTime->add($interval)->format('Y');

$dateTime = new DateTime();
$thisYear = $dateTime->format('Y');

echo $lastYear . ' ' . $thisYear . ' ' . $nextYear;
```

and by breaking the single string into multiple commands always helps me in reducing confusions.

Comment: Is there any special use here for mixing procedural and object oriented style? `date_format($today->sub($interval), 'Y');` can easily be `$today->sub($interval)->format('Y');`

Comment: But this will give you last year, the year before that and the year before that. Not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @vascowhite you are right, corrected the code. but the last answer was what on the basis of questions code.

Answer (score 6):

Depending upon your version of PHP (>= 5.4), you could tidy it up a bit like this:-

```
$today = new DateTime();
$last_year=(new DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
$next_year = (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
echo $last_year->format('Y').' '.$today->format('Y').' '.$next_year->format('Y');
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/QNKSW).

A more readable and concise option may be to use `\DateTimeImmutable`.

```
$today = new DateTimeImmutable();
$one_year = new DateInterval('P1Y');

$last_year = $today->sub($one_year);
$next_year = $today->add($one_year);
echo $last_year->format('Y').' '.$today->format('Y').' '.$next_year->format('Y');
```

[See it working](https://3v4l.org/eGrDv).

Other than that, this all looks fine. Worry about optimisation when it is needed.

Comment: Was looking for something concise like this. I was doing `((new DateTime())->format('Y'))-1` but this typecasts the datetime to int when subtracting.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. This quite efficient.

```
 echo date("Y");   
 echo date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"));
echo date("Y",strtotime("+1 year"))
```

Comment: OP specifies *using the php DateTime object*, else ok

Comment: Question says that the way he uses seems heavy and use much resources, So I gave this alternative approach to save time & space.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I want to use the DateTime() object to avoid any possible problems with the 2038 time bug.
It is also a way to try to get myself into OO programming. thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$d = new DateTime('now');
$cy = $d->format('Y'); 

// Get previous year 
$d->modify('-1 year');
$py = $d->format('Y');

//Next year : Since object has previous year, so +2 to get next year
$d->modify('+2 year');
$ny = $d->format('Y');

echo "Previous Year: ".$py."<br>";
echo "Current Year : ".$cy."<br>";
echo "Next Year : ".$ny."<br>";

$d = new DateTime('now');
$cm = $d->format('m'); 

$d->modify('-1 month');
$pm = $d->format('m'); 

$d->modify('+2 month');
$nm = $d->format('m');

echo "Previous Month: ".$pm."<br>";
echo "Current Month : ".$cm."<br>";
echo "Next Month : ".$nm."<br>";
?>
```

**Output**

```
Previous Year: 2013
Current Year : 2014
Next Year : 2015
Previous Month: 12
Current Month : 01
Next Month : 02
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use basic math:

```php
$current = date('Y');
$prev = $current - 1;
$next = $current + 1;
```

Comment: I don't want to use date() because of the 2038 time bug.

Comment: @anatak: [then just replace `$current` variable with `$current = date_create()->format('Y');`](https://eval.in/85124)**

Comment: @anatak: I hope in year 2038 all machines will be 64 or more bit, so you won't have this problem with simple `date('Y');` ;)

Comment: I think history has taught us that we use things a lot longer than originally planned. COBOL applications are still running now, being designed in the 70's-80's, Space station MIR was, Hubble telescope and a lot of nuclear power plants are being used after their designed expiration dates.
I think it is best to design something as future proof as possible.

Comment: @anatak: stiil, I think this is kinda different, because today there are already 64-bit servers (at least all my hosts are), where `date('Y')` is working way beyond year 2038. But ok, if you don't wan't to use `date()` just use `date_create()->format('Y');` or `(new DateTime)->format('Y');`.

Answer (score 0):

after reading all the answers I came up with this function to create a dropdown box for year. 
$name is the name of the  
$year_number is the number of years you want to display
this function starts with one year before the current year but you can easily modify it to start displaying from earlier years.

```
function drop_down_box_date_year(&$dbconn, $name, $year_number){
$today = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y');
$startyear = (new DateTime())->sub($interval);
echo '<select name="'.$name.'_year">';
for($i=0;$i<$year_number;$i++){ 
    if($startyear->format('Y')==$today->format('Y')){
        echo '<option value="'.$startyear->format('Y').'" selected>'.$startyear->format('Y').'</option>';           
    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$startyear->format('Y').'">'.$startyear->format('Y').'</option>';
    }
    $startyear->add($interval);
}
echo'</select>';
```

}